# "All der Wein" vs. "Aller Wein"

Tags: pronoun, determiners

As a determiner *"all"* All der Wein... but as a pronoun *"all"* (of it = the wine) is it *"Aller Wein"*?

I think the headline captures the essence of my confusion. And I do have a good grammar book!

> All wine is alcoholic. 
>       Der ganze Wein ist alkoholisch.
>
> It’s all alcoholic.
>         Er ist alle alkoholisch.
>         Aller ist alkoholisch.
>
> All the wine is gone.
>       All der Wein ist weg.
>       Der ganze Wein ist weg.
>
> All of it is gone.
>       Der ganze ist weg.
>       Aller ist weg.

So, can *"all"* decline like *"dieser"* when it's used as a pronoun referring back to a noun that has already been introduced? I'm dying to know this and feel quite compulsive about it...

Comment: In general it works quite well translating *all wine* with *aller Wein* and *all (of) the wine* with *all der Wein*. But I'm sure someone will give an extensive answer. (Please accept the edit to make the question more clear)

Comment: A problem with your question is that your examples do not make sense. "Der ganze Wein ist alkoholisch" is grammatically okay, but it is a nonsense sentence. That's because wine by definition has alcohol. If not - it is no wine. Better use sample sentences that make sense, e.g. "Die ganze Milch ist sauer" - that's a viable sentence because you can have a pallette full of bottled milk, and you find that not only a number of bottles have gone bad but the entire shipment. Now, with such a meaningful sentence an answer would be easier.

Answer (score 2):

You can’t translate „all“ (English) with all(…er/all der in German) in all (!) of your examples given, even though it’s the same grammatical category. „All wine“ ist different from „All the wine“

1. „All wine“ would have to be translated as „Jeder/jeglicher Wein“ and the sentence as a whole might be translated better „Wein ist stets alkoholisch“.
2. „It’s all alcoholic“ needs context to be translated properly, it could mean „ganz und gar alkoholisch“ but also „(Whisky, Wein oder Weinbrand,) es ist alles alkoholisch.“
3. „All the wine“ meaning the whole entity of wine could be „Aller Wein“ just as well as „All der Wein“, there is no significant difference. However it’s hardly contemporary German, we would rather say „Der ganze Wein“ oder „Der komplette Wein“ (and rather „…ist ausgetrunken“ or something similar, more specific than „…ist weg“, but that depends on where and how it’s gone…)
4. No, this („Aller“ / „Der ganze“) doesn’t work in German as a subject. „Alles“ however would be appropriate: „Alles ist weg“ or „Es ist alles weg.“ From the context, the previous sentence we would understand what the statement is about.

Comment: Ich danke dir, Ulrich

Comment: To clarify... All the wine
 (Aller Wein, All der Wein is grammatical but old)
 Der ganze Wein... is preferred (keeping it simple for me)

All of my wine
 All mein Wein (assumed grammatical but altmodisch)
 Mein ganzer Wein
  ...meinen ganzen Wein
  ...mit meinem ganzen Wein